# Laravel 5 - Auth Middleware and Routes

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

I am fairly new to Laravel and have an issue with my Routes, Nav and Auth.

I am building a subscription based system, where certain facilities are available to logged in members, and some features which are available to logged in, and non-logged in users.

My Horizontal Nav bar has some menu items in it which should always be shown, and some which should only be shown when the user is logged in.

I have achieved this by declaring some routes inside a Middleware block, as follows:

```
//Directory (visible whether logged in or not)
Route::get('directory', 'DirectoryController@index');
Route::get('directory/band/{id}', 'DirectoryController@band');
```

And some, which are outside of this..

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    //Events
    Route::get('events', 'EventsController@index');
    Route::get('eventsByRange/{start}/{$end}', 'EventsController@eventsByRange');
}
```

The Nav menu has some checks to see if there is a logged in user, and displays extra menu items if there is, as follows (I am logged in now!)

```
    <li><a href="/directory">Directory</a></li>
    @if (Auth::guest())
        <li><a href="/features">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="/plans">Plans</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('login') }}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
    @else
        <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
    @endif
```

The problem is, that when I navigate to a route which is outside the Middleware block, such as '/directory', the Nav bar seems to lose its logged in status, and all the extra menu items ('/events' for example) disappear. If I then navigate back to a page which is protected by Auth middleware, then all the options re-appear.

I cannot understand why this is happening and how to address it.

In other words, the Directory controller seems to lose all track of whether I am logged in or not, and then the menu items do not show.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - I guess I am implementing this incorrectly.

Regards

James

Comment: I guess you need to group the routes using the 'web' middleware as anything that's not given a web middleware will not have cookies or session or CSRF functional. Refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups